# Providing certificates to linkerd and linkerd-viz

Tags: kubernetes-helm, linkerd

I am using [`linkerd-viz`](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/linkerd2/linkerd-viz) and [`linkerd-control-plane`](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/linkerd2/linkerd-control-plane) helm charts.

The former has `tap.caBundle`,  `tap.crtPEM`, `tap.keyPEM`,  `tapInjector.caBundle`,  `tapInjector.crtPEM`, `tapInjector.keyPEM` values.

The latter has `identityTrustAnchorsPEM`, `identity.issuer.tls.crtPEM`, `identity.issuer.tls.keyPEM` values.

Can I set

`tap.caBundle` == `tapInjector.caBundle`  ==   `identityTrustAnchorsPEM`

AND

`tap.crtPEM` == `tapInjector.crtPEM` == `identity.issuer.tls.crtPEM`

AND

`tap.keyPEM`  == `tapInjector.keyPEM` == `identity.issuer.tls.keyPEM`

?

Is this practice possible and proper?

For example, if I write on  [`helmfile`](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)'s config, it'd be like the snippet below.
(`helmfile` runs `helm` internally. For example, `set:` in yaml is equal to `--set-file` in cli)

```yaml
  - name: linkerd-viz
    set:
      - name: tap.caBundle
        file: values/prod/certs/linkerd.ca.crt
      - name: tap.crtPEM
        file: values/prod/certs/linkerd.tls.crt
      - name: tap.keyPEM
        file: values/prod/certs/linkerd.tls.key
      - name: tapInjector.caBundle
        file: values/prod/certs/linkerd.ca.crt
      - name: tapInjector.crtPEM
        file: values/prod/certs/linkerd.tls.crt
      - name: tapInjector.keyPEM
        file: values/prod/certs/linkerd.tls.key

  - name: linkerd-control-plane
    set:
      - name: identityTrustAnchorsPEM
        file: values/prod/certs/linkerd.ca.crt
      - name: identity.issuer.tls.crtPEM
        file: values/prod/certs/linkerd.tls.crt
      - name: identity.issuer.tls.keyPEM
        file: values/prod/certs/linkerd.tls.key
```